# Search the memory of another process

Tags: delphi

Is there a fast way to search/scan the memory of a process for a specific value, 
find the location of this value, edit and save it?

There are examples like [Peeping Tom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/peepingtom/files/peepingtom/104b%20-%20Delphi/), but it's very slow and has issues with Vista & Win7.

Comment: Assuming that Peeping Tom doesn't do something pretty ridiculous - its probably scanning the process stack and the heap (especially) in the fastest possible manner. If the heap is big, then you are bound to get a performance hit. So you may not find anything faster.

Comment: Why? It is pretty trivial to implement that yourself. Look at `VirtualQueryEx`

Comment: @Kabamaru: Share your findings! Did you implement the solution as recommended in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to debug the process (i.e. the equivalent of attaching the process to your custom debugger) and use [ReadProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to read and [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to write.

This is what the [Delphi Code Coverage project](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/) is doing to insert breakpoints to track code coverage at runtime.

Look at the class [DebugProcess](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/source/browse/trunk/CodeCoverage/DebugProcess.pas), it has methods to read and write to the memory of the debugged process.